# no text entry or keyboard capabilities in firefox browser when running in firejail, or regular usrspace after reboot

Tags: keyboard, firefox, pulseaudio, ibus, memory-leak

Ubuntu 16.0.4.3
Gnome Desktop

I have no text entry or keyboard capabilities in my firefox browser when running in firejail, or regular usrspace.

Running:

> firejail firefox --noprofile

results in a firefox browser that **will** connect successfully to bookmarked links, but **wont** receive any keyboard input. I then tried running firefox outside firejail in regular usrspace and experienced the same no-kb-working results. I got here by running gnome-www-browser in terminal, which opens a fully functional firefox.

Error messages in terminal:

> (firefox:12): IBUS-WARNING **: Events queue growing too big, will
> start to drop.
>
> (firefox:12): IBUS-WARNING **: Events queue growing too big, will
> start to drop.
>
> [Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
>
> [Parent 12] WARNING: pipe error (84): Connection reset by peer: file
> /build/firefox-l1g98U/firefox-56.0+build6/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc,
> line 353
> *** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for
> id: telemetry_modules_ping

Dmesg errors:

> [pulseaudio] shm.c: shm_open() failed: No such file or directory
> shm_open() failed: No such file or directory
>
> gnome-session[1768]: console.error: duckduckgo_plus:
>
> gnome-session[1768]:   Nothing to show. gnome-session[1768]:
>
> shm_open() failed: No such file or directory gnome-session[1768]:
>
> shm_open() failed: No such file or directory gnome-session[1768]:
>
> console.error: duckduckgo_plus: gnome-session[1768]:   Nothing to
> show. gnome-session[1768]: shm_open() failed: No such file or
> directory

So my best guess is a shared memory failure messing up the ibus- but nothing in my logs remotely points to its root cause beyond these few reports. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can track down and isolate this?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with chromium and skypeforlinux on ubuntu 16.04.1
I have solved this by adding GTK_IM_MODULE=xim in firetools settings like this

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim firejail skypeforlinux
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim firejail chromium-browser
```

so run from terminal with command line below or go to firetools and press right button on firefox icon and select Edit option to set

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim firejail firefox
```

Comment: This works for me.